# sendTransfer() 'Invalid transaction hash' when running mainnet but fine on testnet

Tags: iri-legacy-api, javascript

When running a `sendTransfer()` on a testnet node (`https://testnet140.tangle.works`) I can attach without any problems. When I try to use a mainnet node (`http://nodes.iota.fm:80`) I get `Invalid transaction hash`.

Here is my call: `iota.api.sendTransfer(seed, 3, 9, transferData, callback)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was writing this out I realized I might try changing the weight to `14` and that did it! Too bad the error wasn't a little more descriptive!